# The getter 'accentColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'

Tags: flutter, dart

When running Gradle task 'assembleDebug' it fails with this error:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/rflutter_alert-2.0.4/lib/src/dialog_button.dart:63:43: Error: The getter 'accentColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
 - 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'accentColor'.
        color: color ?? Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

this is the corresponding part from `dialog_button.dart` from `material` package

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: color ?? Theme.of(context).accentColor,
    gradient: gradient,
    borderRadius: radius,
    border: border,
),
```

installed versions:

```
Flutter 3.10.0-5.0.pre.29 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f74054467b (2 hours ago) • 2023-04-14 07:17:25 -0400
Engine • revision 4b96e38c92
Tools • Dart 3.1.0 (build 3.1.0-4.0.dev) • DevTools 2.23.1
```

theme settings in `main.dart`:

```
theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
      builders: Map<TargetPlatform, PageTransitionsBuilder>.fromIterable(
        TargetPlatform.values,
        value: (dynamic _) =>
            const FadeUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder(), //applying old animation
      ),
    ),
    textSelectionTheme: const TextSelectionThemeData(
      cursorColor: Colors.grey,
      selectionHandleColor: Colors.grey,
    ),
    inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 2),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

How to fix it?

Comment: have you declared your custom theme file?

Comment: ThemeData's accent properties have been deprecated.

use `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary`

Comment: @RohanJariwala I added the corresponding code

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't update files in your `.pub_cache`. You will lose all your changes with the next `pub get`. Instead add `chewie_audio` to your `dev_dependencies` in `pubspec.yaml` like this:

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  chewie_audio: ^1.5.0
```

Once the original `chewie` package fixes this issue you can remove it from `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for pointing out con of updating files in .pub_cache

Answer (score 8):

`Theme.of(context).accentColor` is deprecated on  my version(3.7.9) possible removed on updated one, You can use

```dart
Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
```

Comment: but I don't use directly `Theme.of(context).accentColor` in my code. it's from `material` package, is not it?

Comment: yap it is from material `color: color ?? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,`

Comment: Got the issue>> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56918

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue after upgrading flutter to 3.10.0.
to resolve this error just go to file `material_controls.dart` and do the changes as follow.

Here is the path of file: `/home/<username>/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/chewie_audio-1.3.0/lib/src/material_controls.dart`

`.pub_cache` file will show in hidden files.

Around line 242-243, change:

```
playedColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
handleColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
```

To:

```
playedColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
handleColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
```

Comment: Changing values in the pub cache is only a temporary fix, next time the pub cache is cleared your changes will be wiped out.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the

```
accentColor
```

to

```
colorScheme.secondary
```

Answer (score 0):

- 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'accentColor'.
  widget.glowColor ?? Theme.of(context).accentColor;

Answer (score 0):

So, this issue is arising because of the packages. So, to completely resolve run command

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

then fix all the changes according to the updated library. You can resolve this problem by the above answer but to ensure this issue will not arise again. This is a complete solution.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: @tchrist Thank you. What I did was rewrite my answer from ChatGPT so, others can understand better. You are also right so, I edited the answer and write it in my own words.

Answer (score 0):

> I Updated my flutter version from 3.10 to 3.13  and started getting the issues

Issue 1: Min SDK version issue. That i updated to ">=2.12.0"

Issue 2: "The getter 'accentColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'

This is resolved with the command -  **flutter pub upgrade --major-versions**
(I found this in flutter documentation - https://docs.flutter.dev/release/upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

Simply update line:

```
color: color ?? Theme.of(context).accentColor,
```

to:

```
color: color ?? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue when I upgrading flutter version. And I fix it:

```
dev_dependencies:
  chewie: ^1.7.0
  chewie_audio: ^1.5.0
```