# Error: The getter 'accentColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'

Tags: android, flutter

I'm working on a Flutter project, and I've encountered an issue with the theme property in my MyApp class. Here's my original code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried removing the theme section,hoping the default theme would suffice for the time being, as I can confirm that the error is indeed related to the theme, and rule out other possibilities, but it results in the same error.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/C:/Users/irsha/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/get-4.1.4/lib/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart:325:49: Error: The getter 'accentColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
 - 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('/C:/Users/irsha/AppData/Local/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'accentColor'.
                    color: buttonColor ?? theme.accentColor,
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Can someone please provide guidance on how to remove or modify the theme property without causing errors and how to work with the default theme in Flutter?

Thank you for your help!

**update**
I could see only one instance of accentColor in the `theme_data.dart` which is

```
 colorScheme ??= ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
      primarySwatch: primarySwatch,
      accentColor: isDark ? Colors.tealAccent[200]! : primarySwatch[500]!,
      cardColor: cardColor,
      backgroundColor: isDark ? Colors.grey[700]! : primarySwatch[200]!,
      errorColor: Colors.red[700],
      brightness: effectiveBrightness,
    );
```

Comment: Try replacing `theme.accentColor` with `Theme.of(context).accentColor`

Comment: where? I don't see any such lines which include `theme.accentColor` in my code, I guess the line which includes calling theme.accentColor isn't part of my project's code, I guess it is in the flutter framework instead. Should I go there and change it?

Comment: I could see only one instance of accentColor in the ``theme_data.dart`` which is 

` colorScheme ??= ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
      primarySwatch: primarySwatch,
      accentColor: isDark ? Colors.tealAccent[200]! : primarySwatch[500]!,
      cardColor: cardColor,
      backgroundColor: isDark ? Colors.grey[700]! : primarySwatch[200]!,
      errorColor: Colors.red[700],
      brightness: effectiveBrightness,
    );`

Comment: The error shows location is in lib/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart, may you please provide code in there so we can troubleshoot? issue could be caused by a package that you're using

Comment: Check out similar issue solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76015716/the-getter-accentcolor-isnt-defined-for-the-class-themedata

Comment: You are potentially depending on an old version of the `get` package. First thing I would try is upgrading to the latest release `get: ^4.6.6`. Also would be great if you could provide the output of `flutter doctor -v` on your computer

Comment: @Texv, It worked!! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accent color is deprecated and has been replaced by ColorScheme.secondary

Instead of:

```
Color myColor = Theme.of(context).accentColor;
```

You should use:

```
Color myColor = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary;
```

Check https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/theme-data-accent-properties for more details.